# How to get KNN linearly hybridised by two similarities?

Tags: correlation, k-nearest-neighbour, recommender-system

I'm writing a KNN (collaborative filtering) hybrid similarity recommender and I need some advice. It is based on [this paper](http://arantxa.ii.uam.es/%7ECantador/doc/2014/ecweb14.pdf).

I've currently got 2 datasets. The first one is `ratings` (approximately 3500 films, 1,028,751 ratings) and the second one is `personality` (1812 users) where the personality of the user is measured using a FFM vector. They are from [here](https://grouplens.org/datasets/personality-2018/).

**The similarity between 2 users is calculated as follows:**

sim(u,v) =  A*sim_{ratings}(u,v) + (1-A)*sim_{personality}(u,v)

The rating similarities and personality similarities are both done using a Pearson correlation, as opposed to only ratings similarity (which is supported in some recommender libraries)

I've tried to implement things from scratch (i.e. build a personality-personality similarity matrix and then a ratings-ratings similarity matrix between users with the intention of combining them) but I'm running into a lot of optimisation issues, so I am back at the drawing board.

What approach should I take from here?